# Unable to export public keys with gpg using --keyring

Tags: gpg

Using the `--keyring` option, I'm unable to export public keys with `gpg`:

```
$ gpg -vv --armor --keyring pubring.gpg --export
gpg: writing to stdout
gpg: WARNING: nothing exported
```

Yet it works with `--homedir`:

```
$ gpg --armor --homedir . --export 
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.14 (GNU/Linux)
...
```

What's the reason for this? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the gpg man page:

> ```
> --keyring file
>              Add file to the current list of  keyrings.   If  file  begins
>              with  a  tilde  and  a slash, these are replaced by the $HOME
>              directory. If the filename does not contain a  slash,  it  is
>              assumed  to  be  in  the  GnuPG home directory ("~/.gnupg" if
>              --homedir or $GNUPGHOME is not used).
> ```

The filename given to `--keyring` (and other options, like `--secret-keyring` and `--trustdb-name`) must have a slash in it, otherwise gpg looks for it in the GnuPG home directory.

You would want to use:

```
gpg -vv --armor --keyring ./pubring.gpg --export
```